# How to generate a custom text file for Entity objects

Tags: c#

**Preface:** I am writing a suite of programs that retrieves files from a shared drive, translates them into a few tables in a database, enables users to perform CRUD operations on the records in the DB (through MVC4 ASP.NET web application), and then reassemble the records in the database to the same file formats and FTP the files back to the mainframe. The files represent extracted data from a mainframe VSAM file and I have no control over the format. There are other projects coming up that are of a similar vain - retrieve, translate, edit, assemble, and upload mainframe extract files. Everything is complete, but the way I wrote the code to assemble the files is not reusable, and is only specific to the Entity objects in the current projects domain model.

**Oppurtunity:** Because the data in the files of the other upcoming projects are in a very similar format, I would like to have some resuable code to reassemble those files too.

**Data:** The below represents some mocked file data. Each line of text (i'll call it a record for now) in the file can be a specific length (80 bytes in this case). The record can be a comment which is prefixed with an asterisk. Uncommented records can be of 4 different types.

- Line
- Sequence Trailer
- Table Trailer
- Tables Type Trailer

A 'Line' belongs to a 'Sequence' (the sequence number - unique only to the Table). A 'Sequence' belongs to a 'Table' (the table key - unique to the File). A 'Table' has a type, tables are ordered by their type and key in the file.

The Line has the following in order:

1. Three digit business code.
2. Three character Table type.
3. Five character Table key.
4. Nine digit Sequence Number. left zero padded.
5. Six digit Line Number. left zero padded.
6. Three character action code.
7. One character incl. code.
8. Five digit values length.
9. Rest are values.

The Sequence Trailer has the following in order:

1. Three digit business code.
2. Three character Table type.
3. Five character Table key.
4. Nine digit Sequence Number. left zero padded.
5. Five digit filler ('9').
6. Nine digit count of lines in Sequence (left zero padded).

Table Trailer has the following in order:

1. Three digit business code.
2. Three character Table type.
3. Five character Table key.
4. Fourteen digit filler ('9').
5. Nine digit count of Sequences in table (left zero padded).

The Tables Trailer has the following in order:

1. Three digit business code.
2. Three character Table type.
3. Nineteen digit filler ('9').
4. Nine digit count of Tables (with #2 table type) in files. (left zero padded).

Tables Trailer occurs after each ordered set of tables in the file.

```
************************************************************************
*    TABLE 00001  -  SOME MORE COMMENTS
*          04/04/11  CREATED TABLE
************************************************************************
* COMMENT FOR SEQ 1
720PFT0000100000001000001PROI00011E1037-E1039
720PFT0000100000001000002PGMI000016
720PFT0000100000001000003RTN 00004 NAC
720PFT0000100000001099999000000003
* COMMENT FOR SEQ 2
720PFT0000100000003000001PROI00011E1037-E1039
720PFT0000100000003000002CLSI000037,8
720PFT0000100000003000003MEDE000010
720PFT0000100000003000004RTN 00004 NAC
720PFT0000100000003099999000000004
720PFT0000199999999999999000000002
720PFT9999999999999999999000000001
```

**Code:** The following represents the Entities in the domain model (I excluded related Entities for brevity):

```
[Table("Line",Schema="Pft")]
public class Line
{
    #region Entity Properties

    [Key]
    public int LineId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public short LineNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SequenceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int IncludeExcludeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int QualifierId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("PlanFlexTable")]
    public int PlanFlexTableId { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

[Table("Sequence", Schema="Pft")]
public class Sequence
{
    #region Entity Properties

    [Key]
    public int SequenceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(511)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

[Table("PlanFlexTable", Schema = "Pft")]
public class PlanFlexTable
{
    #region Entity Properties

    [Key]
    public int PlanFlexTableId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 5)]
    [Required]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Table Comment")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public int PlanFlexTableTypeId { get; set; }

    public int UpdateHistoryId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(3)]
    [Required]
    public string PlanId { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

**Summary:** I am seeking advice for a reusable way of generating files like the one I mentioned above. Currently I have one class that takes an IEnumerable of the PlanFlexTable entity and iterates over it assembling the file to upload. I have considered using reflection to create some attributes to put on the Entities to define how the file should be built; However, I would really appreciate some more feedback and ideas on other possibilities.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not easy to read all these textbooks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to to generate code dynamically.... try T4? You can have a base template for your entity class(es) with the schema essentials (keying etc..) and fill up the rest of the class based off the VSAM files (for which you'd have a reusable parser..)

The rest of your CRUD tool is likely re-usable given the (generated) entity classes and DB tables?

Comment: I apologize if I was not clear. I don't need to generate the Entity class code dynamically. I want to be able to generate the file extract (in the 'Data' section of my post) based on instances of the Entity classes which is why I was considering reflection (Since the process I am after is similar to serialization).